# WCF client and service authentication via certificates

Tags: wcf

I just  don’t seem to get my head around this. I need to enable via code or config, a way where in the client can authenticate the service and also service can authenticate the client.

What does
`<Identity>` play a role in this?

Can i specify the client credential here? 
And what needs to be filled here

```
<serviceCertificate>
   </serviceCertificate>
   <windowsAuthentication>
   </windowsAuthentication>
```

I need to understand the way the certificate are exchanged and various ways of doing so.

Comment: This is a very broad question, in essence you're asking "how does WCF authentication via certificates work?". There are broad answers too, you could start with MSDN, for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731899.aspx).